# k8s weave installation: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, cni

I am trying to install weave plugin CNI on k8s cluster using:

```
kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')&password-secret=weave-passwd&env.IPALLOC_RANGE=10.96.0.0/16"
```

But i am seeing this error:

```
error: error parsing https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=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&password-secret=weave-passwd&env.IPALLOC_RANGE=10.96.0.0/16*: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 42: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kubernetes/kube-addon/) says you should do

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/releases/download/v2.8.1/weave-daemonset-k8s.yaml
```

The URL you're using yields a HTTP 301 which, if followed, gives you some HTML. That obviously yields errors when parsed as YAML.